# How can I restrict a KDTree query to a subset of the nodes?

Tags: python, data-structures, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor, minimum-spanning-tree

tl;dr
I need a way to find "Foreign Nearest Neighbors" using a KDTree or some other spatial data structure. i.e find the nearest neighbor in a subset of the tree.

I built a MST algorithm that uses a KDTree to find nearest neighbors. However eventually it needs to look beyond nearest neighbors and into "Nearest Foreign Neighbors" as to connect distant nodes. My first approach simply iteratively increases k-nn parameter until the query returns a node in the subset. I cache k as each time the function is called the breadth of its search is expanded and there is no point in searching the previous k < k_cache.

```
def FNNd(kdtree, A, b):
"""
kdtree -> nodes in subnet -> coord of b -> index of a
returns nearest foreign neighbor a∈A of b
"""
a = None
b = cartesian_projection(b)
k = k_cache[str(b)] if str(b) in k_cache else 2

while a not in A:
    #scipy kdtree where query -> [dist], [idx]
    _, nn = kdtree.query(b, k=k)
    a = nn[-1][k-1]
    k += 1

k_cache[str(b)] = k-1
#return NN a ∈ A of b 
return a
```

However this is quite 'hacky' and inefficient, so I was thinking I could implement a KDTree myself that stops traversing when doing so would result in subtrees that doesn't include the restricted subset. Then the nearest neighbor in the subset would have to be that left or right branch. After many attempts I can't seem to get this to actually work. Is there a flaw in my logic? A better way to do this? A better Data Structure?

Heres my KDTree

```
class KDTree(object):    
def __init__(self, data, depth=0, make_idx=True):
    self.n, self.k = data.shape

    if make_idx:
        # index the data
        data = np.column_stack((data, np.arange(self.n)))
    else:
        # subtract the indexed dimension in later calls
        self.k -= 1

    self.build(data, depth)

def build(self, data, depth):

    if data.size > 0:
        # get the axis to pivot on
        self.axis = depth % self.k
        # sort the data
        s_data = data[np.argsort(data[:, self.axis])]
        # find the pivot point
        point = s_data[len(s_data) // 2]

        # point coord
        self.point = point[:-1]
        # point index
        self.idx = int(point[-1])

        # all nodes below this node
        self.children = s_data[np.all(s_data[:, :-1] != self.point, axis=1)]
        # branches
        self.left  = KDTree(s_data[: len(s_data) // 2], depth+1, False)
        self.right = KDTree(s_data[len(s_data) // 2 + 1: ], depth+1, False)
    else:
        # empty node
        self.axis=0
        self.point = self.idx = self.left = self.right = None
        self.children = np.array([])

def query(self, point, best=None):

    if self.point is None:
        return best

    if best is None:
        best = (self.idx, self.point)

    # check if current node is closer than best
    if distance(self.point, point) < distance(best[1], point):
        best = (self.idx, self.point)

    # continue traversing the tree
    best = self.near_tree(point).query(point, best)

    # traverse the away branch if the orthogonal distance is less than best
    if self.orthongonal_dist(point) < distance(best[1], point):
        best = self.away_tree(point).query(point, best)    
    return best 

 def orthongonal_dist(self, point):
    orth_point = np.copy(point)
    orth_point[self.axis] = self.point[self.axis]
    return distance(point, self.point)

def near_tree(self, point):
    if point[self.axis] < self.point[self.axis]:
        return self.left
    return self.right

def away_tree(self, point):
    if self.near_tree(point) == self.left:
        return self.right
    return self.left
```

[EDIT] Updated attempt, however this doesn't guarantee a return

```
def query_subset(self, point, subset, best=None):

    # if point in subset, update best
    if self.idx in subset:
        # if closer than current best, or best is none update
        if best is None or distance(self.point, point) < distance(best[1], point):
            best = (self.idx, self.point)

    # Dead end backtrack up the tree
    if self.point is None:
        return best

    near = self.near_tree(point)
    far = self.away_tree(point)

    # what nodes are in the near branch
    if near.children.size > 1:
        near_set = set(np.append(near.children[:, -1], near.idx))
    else: near_set = {near.idx}

    # check the near branch, if its nodes intersect with the queried subset
    # otherwise move to the away branch
    if any(x in near_set for x in subset):
        best = near.query_subset(point, subset, best)
    else:
        best = far.query_subset(point, subset, best)

    # validate best, by ensuring closer point doesn't exist just beyond partition
    if best is not None:
        if self.orthongonal_dist(point) < distance(best[1], point):
            best = far.query_subset(point, subset, best)    

    return best
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem nor your code but combining Nearest Foreign Neighbors with k-D trees raises the following suggestions: 1) if doable, create a different tree for every set of points that are foreign to the possible queries or 2) use a single tree for all points but tag every subtree with flags telling which color it does not contain.

Comment: To summarize: Given a set A and B, find the nearest neighbor a in A of point b in B. Creating a tree for every set is inefficient as the sets are continuously being modified as the MST is built. i.e. B is the set of nodes already in the MST while A is {nodes in Graph - MST}. 2) is more along the lines of the approach I am trying to take, however I cant get the traversal rules down..

Comment: The modified traversal rule is easy: if a node doesn't contain any foreign color, ignore it. Anyway with a dynamic tree the situation is different as you need to keep the flags updated. But you could look at the problem differently and consider removing the points from the tree as you consume them.

Comment: Getting closer, see revised attempt in the Edit. However it doesn't always return a neighbor if it never encounters a point in the subset during traversal.